# Is it possible to drag an HTML element out of another element and trigger a change with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a container element that you can drag objects around in. I want it it so that if you drag an element out of the container (when the mouse crosses the border of the containing div) the element you're dragging to change. How do I arrange this?

```
$("#container img").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 100
});
```

Once the image crosses the bounds of "#container" I should be able to change the image source.

Comment: the element i'm draging is an 'img' and once it's crossed a certain line, i want to change the 'img' src attribute.

Comment: How are you setting up the dragging behavior? jQuery UI? Any sample code you can post?

Comment: What is the `overflow` setting of `#container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({ out: function() {
      $('#draggable').css('background-color', 'white');
    }, over: function() {
  $('#draggable').css('background-color', 'blue');
}
  });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="droppable" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; background-color: green;">
<div id="draggable" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid pink; background-color: blue;">
```